# SSIS - Combine Duplicate Rows

Tags: ssis

I have this issue to where I have a flat file with some duplicates. I don't want to simply remove the duplicates as I need to combine data for the affected duplicates. Here some sample data that I have

```
User ID             Name                  Home Number         Work Number
  1                 Doe,John              555-555-1212         
  1                 Doe,John                                  888-888-8888
  2                 Doe,Jane              123-456-7890
  3                 Test, User            777-777-7777
```

What I would like to do is combine the duplicates so that the referenced home number and work number that have the same user_ID are applied. Here is what my expected results would look like

```
User ID             Name                  Home Number         Work Number
  1                 Doe,John              555-555-1212        888-888-8888
  2                 Doe,Jane              123-456-7890
  3                 Test, User            777-777-7777
```

Here are some things to keep in mind

1. As indicated by the sample data listed above, not all rows are duplicates
2. I actually have many more fields than what's listed above. There are other number fields also, such as cell phone number
3. The phone number field may not be the exact length. Some of them could have parenthesis.
4. The user ID is unique for each user

Sort transformation won't work as it will delete one of the duplicates above and I lose one of the fields. I'm thinking maybe Fuzzy Lookup. But I never used that before.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if row 1 in your initial set had a work number of 888-555-1212? What do you do when there is a conflict in values?

Comment: I would import the flat file as is into a staging table and use a stored proc to combine the dupes and import to the final destination table.

Comment: @billinkc It's ok to have the home and work as the same values. I'm mostly interested in consolidating the data

Comment: @user1937434 But it wouldn't have the same value. One record would specify the work number of 888-555-1212 and the other specifies 888-888-8888. Which one is correct? Or, if not correct, least wrong or most right? For the same User ID, you want to consolidate the data down to a single row. Your first business rule appears to be that when there is data present and absent, preserve the non-empty data. That's reasonable. The question now becomes, what do you do when there is a conflict in values? Is it a crap shoot and either value is equally acceptable? Do your business owners accept that?

Comment: @billinkc I see what you saying. However, that scenario will not happen. These results were originated from a Union All export. There won't be multiple home numbers for the same user ID. I was thinking I could resolve this by loading the data into a staging table. Then updating the column with updating the home number based upon the user_ID value. But now that I am thinking about it, that won't work since there is a blank value.

Answer (score 0):

This would be much simpler if it were in a database, but if you are really, really sure that you won't have duplicates then you can do something like this:

- First read the file in using your flat file source
- Use Multicast to split your data into a "main" path plus 1 for each phone number or other data item you wish to combine
- On each path use Aggregate component to group your user_ID and one of the phone number fields. On "main" path just aggregate on user_ID and any other information you wish to keep, like name.
- Combine the different paths using Merge Join component. Remember to use left join.
- Output where needed.

If the data was in a DB already then you could replace the different branches with a series of Lookups (using `select distinct user_ID, phoneNumber from Table`)